# Kann das Adverb "einerseits...andererseits" auch dreiteilig sein?

Tags: phrase

Kann man Folgendes sagen:

> Einerseits.... andererseits...andererseits.

Wenn man z.B. auf drei Aspekte bzw. Seiten einer Sache verweisen möchte.
Oder wie sollte man das zweite  *andererseits*  ersetzen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"einerseits ... andererseits" wird meistens nur mit 2 Aspekten verwendet, wie pro und contra. Man wird es verstehen, wenn Du weitere "(wiederum) andererseits..." nachschiebst, aber es klingt umständlich.

Wenn Du einen dritten Aspekt aufzeigen willst, könntest Du ihn anders einleiten, z.B. mit "ausserdem" oder "davon abgesehen".

Comment: Oder auch: "einerseits... andererseits... und dritterseits", aber das ist keineswegs üblich so sondern eine kreative Sprachverwendung, die dementsprechend auch nicht überall einsetzbar ist.

Comment: Nur so ein Gedanke: Warum nicht... einerseits ... andererseits "... drittens" bzw. "... des Weiteren" bzw. "... oder aber auch" bzw. "... möglicherweise" und viele weitere Alternativen ...